# Prove that a directed tree does not have a path from a descendant to its parent

Tags: graph-theory

Prove:
Let T = (V, E) be a directed tree. If v is a vertex of V and u is a descendant of v, then there is no path from u to v.

My idea is that if u is a descendant of v, then there exist a path from v to u.
Suppose that there is also a path from u to v, then we have a contradiction of being in a directed tree.

It seems so obvious, thus I'm having trouble proving it formally.

Comment: HINT: You have a cycle.

Comment: Looks like you've already made a formal proof by contradiction in your second paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Community wiki answer to allow the question to be marked as answered:

You're right. As noted in the comments, you could make the contradiction you derive more explicit by exhibiting the concatenation of the path from $u$ to $v$ and the path from $v$ to $u$ as a cycle.